# Setting QWidget fullscreen on multi monitor setup

Tags: linux, qwidget, multiple-monitors, qt5.3

i have a linux system with 2 monitor outputs (1920x1080). I arranged them to have a desktop size of 1920x2160.
Now i wanted to run a Qt Applcation, which starts in full screen mode covering the 1920x2160 desktop.
I tried:

```
QWidget::setFullScreen() -> The QWidget is maximized across 1 monitor
QWidget::setGeometry(0,0,1920,2160) -> The QWidget is also maximized across 1 monitor
```

Even if i do:

```
QWidget::move(0,0) & QWidget::resize(1920,2160) -> The QWidget does not exceed the size of the 1 monitor.
```

But if i move and resize the QWidget manually with the mouse, i can resize it to 1920x2160.
I was not able to do that programmatically.
Maybe someone has a hint for me on what i am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of the problem is the window manager. If i started the X server without any window manager, it was possible to call

```
QWidget::setGeometry(...)
```

and the window sized itself across all connected displays.
So i mistakenly assumed that Qt is the problem.